# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java4 in java.library.path in Android unit test

Tags: java, android, kotlin, unit-testing, opencv

I have been trying to integrate OpenCV into my Android app. I was successfully able to integrate and run it. However, when running unit tests which initialises OpenCV library results in an error stating

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java4 in java.library.path: /Users/robersa/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:`

steps I have followed so far,

1. Downloaded the OpenCV lib from [here](https://opencv.org/releases/)
2. Extracted the file and imported the module into my Android project
3. Tested the library by running it on real device
4. While creating a unit test with the below code, it throws the aforeementioned error

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class SimilarityTransformTest {

    private val transform: LinearTransform = SimilarityTransform()

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        OpenCVLoader.initDebug()
    }

    @Test
    fun getTransformationVector_calculateVector() {
        val landmarkMat = Mat(5, 2, CvType.CV_32F)
        val landmark = FacialLandmark(
            PointF(395.0f, 317.0f),
            PointF(536.0f, 315.0f),
            PointF(440.0f, 415.0f),
            PointF(409.0f, 478.0f),
            PointF(534.0f, 475.0f)
        )
        landmarkMat.put(0, 0, *landmark.toDoubleArray())
        val alignmentMat = Mat(5, 2, CvType.CV_32F)
        val alignment = listOf(
            Point(87.530518, 118.16298),
            Point(168.07269, 117.71749),
            Point(128.0576, 163.96938),
            Point(94.969826, 211.12115),
            Point(161.66835, 210.75224)
        ).flatMap { arrayOf(it.x, it.y).asIterable() }
            .toDoubleArray()
        alignmentMat.put(0, 0, *alignment)
        val result = transform.getTransformationVector(landmarkMat, alignmentMat)
        val expected = Mat(2, 3, CvType.CV_32F)
        expected.put(0, 0, 0.55679309, -0.013752065, -124.12323, 0.013752068, 0.55679309, -64.73703);

        assertEquals(expected, result)
    }
}

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java4 in java.library.path: /Users/robersa/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.opencv.android.StaticHelper.loadLibrary(StaticHelper.java:64)
    at org.opencv.android.StaticHelper.initOpenCVLibs(StaticHelper.java:95)
    at org.opencv.android.StaticHelper.initOpenCV(StaticHelper.java:39)
    at org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader.initDebug(OpenCVLoader.java:107)
    at com.yoti.mobile.android.ai.core.warp.SimilarityTransformTest.setup(SimilarityTransformTest.kt:28)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.invokeMethod(RunBefores.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:589)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$2(SandboxTestRunner.java:290)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:99)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I would appreciate any help to understand why the `opencv_java4` cannot be loaded for unit tests but works well while running the app on a device/emulator.